# Which elements does the jQuery expression $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])') target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery, and have found a code snippet that will scroll to a certain part of a page pointed to by local, or 'anchor' links.

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

        if (target.length) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 500);
          return false;
        }

      }
 });
```

I understand that it must select links with local hrefs, but was wondering exactly what the difference is between the two 'clauses' of the selector.

Comment: For reference, compare jQuery's [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) and [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: The second part is a concession to developers that abuse links as JavaScript triggers, in places where they actually should use buttons :p

Comment: Here's further reading about the spec, not specific to jQuery https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk (`*`) character after the attributes in jQuery denotes the **[attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**.

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')
```

Breaking this down:

- `a`: Target all the **[`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)** tags
- `[href*=#]`: Target all the **[`href`](https://html.com/attributes/a-href/)** attributes that **contain** `#`.
- `:not([href=#])`: Do *not*  target `href` attributes that have an `href` value of **exactly** `#`.

So, in short, the selector targets any `<a>` tags that contain a `#` in their `href` attribute where `#` is not the **only** part of the `href` attribute.

Considering URIs use hashes to denote IDs on the page, this allows the jQuery to scroll to an element on the page, rather than simply 'jump' to it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

It matches anchors with an `href` attribute that includes `#` but is **not only** `#`.

Comment: This is a comment!

Comment: @Ele No, it's not. It's the answer. Don't confuse brevity with comments.

Comment: First I'm not confusing anything.  This kind of question must be answered with a tiny comment.  Period!

Comment: *answered with a comment*. Uh, yes you are confusing brevity with comments. `answer === answer`

Comment: @scottmarcus what?

Comment: @Ele It's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Be nice, fellow developers. @Ele can you refer me to the rule you are attempting to enforce?

Comment: @LarsGyrupBrinkNielsen There is no such rule. Your answer follows the [guidelines for a good answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It's short, but that's fine because it's a simple explanation. Most importantly, it does answer the question. Comments are for slightly off-topic statements or questions back to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

The first rule will match any URL with a hash component, e.g. `<a href="#jump-to-id">`

The second `not` rule filters out any URLs that are *just* an empty hash, e.g., `<a href="#">`

Comment: @EdwardGargan Please post a new question since your latest one is not related to the last one.

Answer (score 3):

`a[href*=#]` gets all links that contains `#`, but `:not([href=#])` excludes links with exactly `#` in their `href` attribute.

This link will be selected:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/here#top" title="">Link</a>
```

But this one not:

```
<a href="#" title="">Link</a>
```